# How to keep encoding inline style HTML

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

I've specified an inline style with a `background-image = url(url with utf8 chars)`. My browser url-encodes the name when it tries to retrieve the image, provoking a 404. Is there a way I can declare encoding in the styles or HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the charset meta tag defined in the head section?

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```